# Android gradle - top level vs module level "build" task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am setting up continuous integration on Android and I am wondering what's the difference between **top level "build"** task and **module level "build"** task. Each says "Assembles and tests this project."

I ran both of them and the **top level said it had 290 actionable tasks** while the **module one had 210 actionable tasks**, so it seems that there is some difference.

To clarify the picture - **presentation** module is my "app" module - I just renamed it previously, this module implements the other modules - domain, data and common.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build task constructs and tests the given level. ie. top level assembles everything, a module task (like `gradle :presentation:build`) will assemble and test just what is necessary for that module.